Kernel 6.9 impossible to remove on Ubuntu 24.04?
I am new with Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 24.04; extract from Mainline:
Kernel 6.10.2 Running
Kernel 6.8.0-39.39 Installed
Kernel 6.8.0-39.39-24.04 Installed

Uninstall old command from Mainline gives the following output:
mainline 1.4.10
uninstall-old 
Uninstalling 6.8.0-39.39                                              
Uninstalling 6.8.0-39.39_24.04
Package linux-headers-6.8.0-39 listed more than once, only processing once.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-24.04 depends on linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 (= 6.8.0-39.39).

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04:
 linux-generic-hwe-24.04 depends on linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 (= 6.8.0-39.39).

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04 depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-image-6.8.0-39-generic:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 depends on linux-image-6.8.0-39-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.8.0-39-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-modules-6.8.0-39-generic:
 linux-image-6.8.0-39-generic depends on linux-modules-6.8.0-39-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-6.8.0-39-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-39-generic:
 linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04 depends on linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-39-generic.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-39-generic (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of linux-headers-6.8.0-39:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic depends on linux-headers-6.8.0-39.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.8.0-39 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-generic-hwe-24.04
 linux-image-generic-hwe-24.04
 linux-headers-6.8.0-39-generic
 linux-image-6.8.0-39-generic
 linux-modules-6.8.0-39-generic
 linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-39-generic
 linux-headers-6.8.0-39
mainline: done

Is this normal? Can someone help? Thank you

It is "normal" in the sense that the problem is clearly not a bug or corrupted file. Seems like your output contains all the information you need for you to solve the problem you inflicted upon yourself. Re-read your output. Perhaps you might diagram the tree of listed dependencies, if that sort of visualization helps you.

Understand, but what should I do to solve the problem? I am new to Ubuntu, so do not know which command(s) to run. I tried to find out how to fix the dpkg dependency error, but did not find a solution. Thank you.

The mainline command uses the Kernel Team PPA, which is not supported. It is for testing and debugging only. It not intended for use by folks "new to Ubuntu". It is for experienced kernel testers and developers. Our advice is to revert all your changes that led to the problem, uninstall mainline, and resume using the supported Ubuntu-provided kernels.

Uninistall the headers: sudo apt purge linux-headers-6.8.0-39 will do it

Not what as asked. OP needs to keep the 6.8 and asked how to remove the 6.9 which should never been installed as it is not supported.
